# find a specific element that shares a class with multiple elements, through jquery

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I'm trying to implement AJAX for a 'like' feature on my website. I have the following code for the create.js.haml file:

```
$(".postlike_unlike").html("#{escape_javascript(render('unlike'))}");
```

My view page loops through all the posts so they all share the same class. Here is a snippet of the view page:

```
- @post.each do |post|
  ...
  %ul.dropdown-menu
    %li
      ...    
    %li
      .postlike_unlike
        .form_for
          ...
```

rendered html:

```
<div class='post content'>
  <p>post 1</p>
</div>
<div class='btn-group dropup'>
  <a class='btn btn-primary' href='/post/3/view?view=true' method='get'>
    <i class='icon-info-sign icon-large'></i>
    View Detailed Post 1
  </a>
  <a class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>
    <span class='caret'></span>
  </a>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
    <li>
      <div class='postlike_unlike'>
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/likes" class="new_like" data-remote="true" id="new_like" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="McQDJsBJF6UHTeMGQNDTBCRzF/PmP5JWWuACqv1ONCA=" /></div>
          <input id="like_likee_id" name="like[likee_id]" type="hidden" value="3" />
          <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">
            <i class='icon-heart-empty icon-large'></i>
            Like this Post
          </a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class='divider'></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class='post content'>
  <p>post 2</p>
</div>
<div class='btn-group dropup'>
  <a class='btn btn-primary' href='/post/3/view?view=true' method='get'>
    <i class='icon-info-sign icon-large'></i>
    View Detailed Post 2
  </a>
  <a class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>
    <span class='caret'></span>
  </a>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
    <li>
      <div class='postlike_unlike'>
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/likes" class="new_like" data-remote="true" id="new_like" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="McQDJsBJF6UHTeMGQNDTBCRzF/PmP5JWWuACqv1ONCA=" /></div>
          <input id="like_likee_id" name="like[likee_id]" type="hidden" value="3" />
          <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">
            <i class='icon-heart-empty icon-large'></i>
            Like this Post
          </a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class='divider'></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**The problem that I'm running into:** When I click the 'like' button, it renders the 'unlike' style on **every** post. I realize that every post has the 'postlike_unlike' class (it's a loop) but I wanted to know whether there was a way to only change the class on the relavant post :ie only update the 'like' on the post that's being liked.

I'm a novice when it comes to jQuery so I'm not familiar if there is a simple way to do what I'm trying to accomplish. If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Can you give us the **rendered HTML** ?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're attaching a click handler to each like/unlike, you can do something like the following

```
$('.postlike_unlike').click(function(){
     //edit the html
     $(this).html("#{escape_javascript(render('unlike'))}");
})
```

on each click it will find the one you clicked (referenced by the `this` keyword), and apply your html.

Comment: unfortunately this does not seem to be working... it does not render anything when i use the code above. I added "alert('ajax works!');" to the end of the create.js.haml file to confirm that ajax is working, and it goes off, but unfortunately, the 'unlike' is not rendering.

Comment: I tried to test your code via the following: $('.postlike_unlike').click(function(){
  alert('ajax works!');
})        I tried to see if the alert would show up. It did not. It looks like it's not finding my postlike_unlike class?

Answer (score 0):

or `$(this).parent()` or something

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a loop, I decided to just make unique div containers for each from by using:

```
%div{:class => "postlike_unlike#{@post.id}}
```

Now in my js file I reference the following:

```
$(".postlike_unlike#{@post.id}").html("#{escape_javascript(render('unlike'))}");
```

This way I'm only changing the 'like' button for the appropriate post.

Thank you everyone for your help.